# Cannot instal h5py

Tags: 16.04, package-management, pip

I have Ubuntu 16.04.5 and trying to install Keras. I need h5py to this, but I have a problem with installing it. When I type:

```
sudo pip install h5py
```

I got this:

```
The directory '/home/nvidia/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/nvidia/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting h5py
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/5d/6f11a5fffc3d8884bb8d6c06abbee0b3d7c8c81bde9819979208ba823a47/h5py-2.8.0.tar.gz (274kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 276kB 1.7MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7 in /home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from h5py) (1.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from h5py) (1.11.0)
Installing collected packages: h5py
  Running setup.py install for h5py ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-49wsh8ku/h5py/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-ltnxb8_8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py
    copying h5py/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py
    copying h5py/version.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py
    copying h5py/h5py_warnings.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py
    copying h5py/highlevel.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py
    copying h5py/ipy_completer.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/selections2.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/dims.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/attrs.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/base.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/datatype.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/dataset.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/files.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/group.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/filters.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/_hl
    copying h5py/_hl/selections.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/_hl
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests
    copying h5py/tests/common.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests/old
    copying h5py/tests/old/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests/old
    copying h5py/tests/old/test_h5t.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests/old
    copying h5py/tests/old/test_dataset.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests/old
    copying h5py/tests/old/test_objects.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests/old
    copying h5py/tests/old/test_group.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests/old
    copying h5py/tests/old/test_h5p.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests/old
    copying h5py/tests/old/test_attrs.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests/old
    copying h5py/tests/old/test_dimension_scales.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests/old
    copying h5py/tests/old/test_datatype.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests/old
    copying h5py/tests/old/test_h5f.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests/old
    copying h5py/tests/old/test_slicing.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests/old
    copying h5py/tests/old/test_h5d_direct_chunk_write.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests/old
    copying h5py/tests/old/test_base.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests/old
    copying h5py/tests/old/test_file.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests/old
    copying h5py/tests/old/test_h5.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests/old
    copying h5py/tests/old/test_selections.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests/old
    copying h5py/tests/old/test_attrs_data.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests/old
    copying h5py/tests/old/test_file_image.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests/old
    creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests/hl
    copying h5py/tests/hl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests/hl
    copying h5py/tests/hl/test_threads.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.5/h5py/tests/hl
    ...
    warning: h5py/api_types_hdf5.pxd:493:4: 'H5T_CSET_ERROR' redeclared
    warning: h5py/api_types_hdf5.pxd:494:4: 'H5T_CSET_ASCII' redeclared
    warning: h5py/api_types_hdf5.pxd:637:2: 'H5Z_filter_t' redeclared
    warning: h5py/api_types_hdf5.pxd:672:6: 'H5Z_ERROR_EDC' redeclared
    warning: h5py/api_types_hdf5.pxd:673:6: 'H5Z_DISABLE_EDC' redeclared
    warning: h5py/api_types_hdf5.pxd:674:6: 'H5Z_ENABLE_EDC' redeclared
    warning: h5py/api_types_hdf5.pxd:675:6: 'H5Z_NO_EDC' redeclared
    [ 8/22] Cythonizing /tmp/pip-install-49wsh8ku/h5py/h5py/h5ac.pyx
    /tmp/pip-install-49wsh8ku/h5py/.eggs/Cython-0.29-py3.5-linux-aarch64.egg/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:367: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: /tmp/pip-install-49wsh8ku/h5py/h5py/h5ac.pxd
      tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
    warning: h5py/api_types_hdf5.pxd:350:2: 'H5D_layout_t' redeclared
    warning: h5py/api_types_hdf5.pxd:357:2: 'H5D_alloc_time_t' redeclared
    warning: h5py/api_types_hdf5.pxd:364:2: 'H5D_space_status_t' redeclared
    warning: h5py/api_types_hdf5.pxd:370:2: 'H5D_fill_time_t' redeclared
    warning: h5py/api_types_hdf5.pxd:376:2: 'H5D_fill_value_t' redeclared
    warning: h5py/api_types_hdf5.pxd:388:7: 'H5F_close_degree_t' redeclared
    warning: h5py/api_types_hdf5.pxd:394:2: 'H5FD_mem_t' redeclared
   ...
    building 'h5py.defs' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.5
    creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.5/tmp
    creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.5/tmp/pip-install-49wsh8ku
    creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.5/tmp/pip-install-49wsh8ku/h5py
    creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.5/tmp/pip-install-49wsh8ku/h5py/h5py
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DH5_USE_16_API -I./h5py -I/tmp/pip-install-49wsh8ku/h5py/lzf -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c /tmp/pip-install-49wsh8ku/h5py/h5py/defs.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.5/tmp/pip-install-49wsh8ku/h5py/h5py/defs.o
    In file included from /home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1821:0,
                     from /home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                     from /home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-49wsh8ku/h5py/h5py/api_compat.h:26,
                     from /tmp/pip-install-49wsh8ku/h5py/h5py/defs.c:654:
    /home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
     #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
      ^
    In file included from /tmp/pip-install-49wsh8ku/h5py/h5py/defs.c:654:0:
    /tmp/pip-install-49wsh8ku/h5py/h5py/api_compat.h:27:18: fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-49wsh8ku/h5py/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-ltnxb8_8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-49wsh8ku/h5py/
```

I tried to clear cache, upgrade pip or use --no-cache-dir. Nothing helps. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

h5py for Python 2.x can be installed from the default repositories in Ubuntu 18.04 and earlier with the following command:

```
sudo apt install python-h5py
```

h5py for Python 3.x can be installed from the default repositories in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu with the following command:

```
sudo apt install python3-h5py
```

HDF5 for Python (h5py) is a general-purpose Python interface to the Hierarchical Data Format library, version 5. HDF5 is a versatile, mature scientific software library designed for the fast, flexible storage of enormous amounts of data.